# В чем разница между pdf.js и pdfjs-dist?

Tags: javascript, pdf

В гитхаб Mozilla есть 2 репозитория:

- https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js
- https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist

В ридми pdf.js написано, что pdfjs-dist просто скомиплированная версия pdfjs располагающаяся на CDN'ах, но зачем скомпилированную версию называть отдельным именем и выделять под нее отдельный репозиторий (тем более в нем другой код)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то я не пойму в чем разница между pdf.js и pdfjs-dist?

Comment: Если вы просто используете библиотеку - то берете pdfjs-dist. Если вы модифицируете библиотеку - то делаете форк pdf.js и дописываете то, что вам нужно. Почему сорс и dist лежат в разных местах?... Потому, что в большинстве случаев нужно либо одно, либо другое.

Comment: @NoSkill, а почему тогда во всех библиотеках так не делают? Ну в смысле что исходники и dist по разных репозиториям не разделяют?

Comment: 1) Потому что паккадж-менеджеры абсолютно все кривые и тупые и не могут сами по желанию разраба разделит сорс, дист, доки, тесты и прочий мусор в пакадже. 2) Потому что нет единного стандарта. 3) Потому, что не у всех разрабов хватает ума сделать чуточку умнее.